# Is an unsuccessful UK asylum seeker allowed to seek asylum in Ireland?

Tags: uk, ireland, serial-refusals, refugees

I am an asylum seeker in the UK. I was refused a few times by the UK Home Office. After I went to court, I was also refused. Then I applied for further submission and was also refused. After that, my solicitor applied for judicial review, it was also refused.

Am I allowed to seek asylum in Ireland? My problem is really serious and I have all of my supporting papers and refusal letters.

Comment: Why not go there and see? You might have to do it quickly, as since you have exhausted your legal avenues in the UK you will probably have to leave soon. Or be removed.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a question to ask your solicitor, instead of random people on the Internet whose qualifications you know nothing about?

Comment: I'm sure the OP asked his solicitor. I don't see anything wrong with posting it here as well to get some additional advice and information. Isn't that the whole idea behind crowd knowledge platforms like this? I'd see the point if it would be someone's only source of information regarding immigration but I don't think that's the case here. There are a lot of very knowledgeable people here so imho it makes a lot of sense to ask it here.

Comment: That's too important for me to know about that. I am really worried about that. Need help if anyone has experience.